# A PHP Error was encountered in code iginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i will make update in codeigniter, but i have found a problem, please help me

in my code i hacve controller

```
  public function edit($id_user = 1)
      {
        $this->load->model('Model_reporter');
        $data['$reporterl'] = $this->model_reporter->getreporter($id_user);
        $data['content']   = 'reporter/reporter_edit';
        $data['judul']     = 'Reporter';
        $data['Sub_judul'] = 'Reporter';
        $this->load->view('admin/admin',$data);
      }
```

in my model

```
  public function edit($id_user = 1)
      {
        $this->load->model('Model_reporter');
        $data['$reporterl'] = $this->model_reporter->getreporter($id_user);
        $data['content']   = 'reporter/reporter_edit';
        $data['judul']     = 'Reporter';
        $data['Sub_judul'] = 'Reporter';
        $this->load->view('admin/admin',$data);
      }
```

but i have problem in view "Message: Undefined variable: reporterl"

```
  <?php
                foreach($reporterl as $keys){
                  ?>
                      <h4 class="mb">Penilaian Berita</h4>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Nama Lengkap</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-4">
```

please help me

Answer (score 2):

Is there should be a "$" ?

```
$data['$reporterl'] = $this->model_reporter->getreporter($id_user);
```

should it be:

```
$data['reporterl'] = $this->model_reporter->getreporter($id_user);
```

Answer (score 1):

why this line is in model

```
 $data['$reporterl'] = $this->model_reporter->getreporter($id_user);
```

there is no need to write this in model .
also this should be

```
 $data['reporterl'] = $this->model_reporter->getreporter($id_user);
```

in your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can load model with:

```
$this->load->model('Model_reporter');
```

or with

```
$this->load->model('model_reporter');// notice difference in first letter
```

But it is important to create and call object named the same as loaded model. In your case:

```
    $data['reporterl'] = $this->Model_reporter->getreporter($id_user);
```

Plus what others say.